# How do I get pictures entered into fields in contact records to be viewable in the contact record?

Tags: contacts, contact-view, contact-types, contact-image, contact-reference

And not just present as file names, or require that the file be opened to view the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! That's a CiviCRM Core Contact Field -> so simply hit Edit on the Contact Record and look for the field: Browse/Upload Image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure. But after you save the field, all you can see is the file name.  I want to be able to see the picture when reviewing the contact record, not the file name. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah that may just Shoreditch extension for me then [we use that with most of our clients]  -> I'll add what I see